# Will there be any security problem to permit non-root user set up a loopback devices?

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-kernel, loop-device

if the user has full access to the image file (iso or disk image), will there be any security problem to permit him set up a loopback device backed by this file ?

```
% ls -al /dev/loop*                                                                                                                                                                  
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   0 Jul 15 16:39 /dev/loop0
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   1 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop1
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   2 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop2
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   3 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop3
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   4 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop4
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   5 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop5
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   6 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop6
brw-rw---T 1 root disk  7,   7 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop7
crw------T 1 root root 10, 237 Jun 17 15:58 /dev/loop-control
```

the `loopX` is belonged to `disk` group

```
% id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),6(disk)
```

I'm in `disk` group. So, I can use the loopback device

```
% /sbin/losetup -f ~/disk.img

% /sbin/losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0809]:2097347 (/home/user/disk.img)
```

But any user isn't in `disk` group can't use the loopback device, is there any problem to permit everyone to use the loopback ?

PS: by using [mount namespace](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/), any user can mount disks, but the root requirement of loopback device prevent user from mounting disk images.

Comment: @goldilocks definitely not, there is no suid or nodev involved by using loopback device.

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood what you are looking for here.

Comment: @goldilocks maybe my question title is misleading

Comment: Probably not, lol, I just see duplicates too easily.  It is a fair and straightforward question.  I don't know the answer, unfortunately.  Although some of the similar questions about mounting have some suggestions about alternatives to granting privileges, I suppose privileges would be easiest.